# Can every congruent number be written as $\dfrac{nm(n-m)(m+n)}{\delta}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I want to show every congruent number $\alpha $ be written as $$\alpha = \dfrac{nm(n-m)(m+n)}{\delta}$$ for some $m,n$ where $\gcd(m,n)=1$, $m\not \equiv n\mod 2 $, $m>n$ and $\delta$ a divisor of $mn$ or $(m-n)(m+n)$. I would also like to show that whenever $\delta$ is a divisor of the square part of $nm(n-m)(m+n)$ then $$\alpha = \dfrac{nm(m-n)(m+n)}{\delta}$$ is a congruent number.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @TShiong see my answer below I cant accept for two days

Comment: @TShiong I want to eventually take this one more step and show if $\alpha = nm(m-n)(m+n)/\delta$ with $\delta$ not square free then $\alpha$ is a congruent number

Comment: wow!! that's great

Comment: @TShiong Its incredible we have all of them now. We can see them they are divisors of Pythagorean triples.

Comment: @TShiong can you help finish the last inclusion. Which $\delta$ can we choose to make $\alpha$ congruent. It seem to need to divide the square part or be a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

Using Euclid's formula
$\quad A=m^2-n^2\quad B=2mn\quad C=m^2+n^2\quad$ area is  by definition
$\quad\alpha=\dfrac{2mn(m^2-n^2)}{2}
=mn(m-n)(m+n).\quad$
Most congruent numbers can be written with $\,m,n\in\mathbb{N}\quad$ e.g $\quad\alpha=6\implies(m,n)=(2,1)\,$
but some
$\quad 
\bigg(\dfrac{20}{3}\bigg)^2 
+ \bigg(\dfrac{3}{2}\bigg)^2 
=\bigg(\dfrac{41}{6}\bigg)^2
\implies\alpha=5\,$ are elusive:
$\quad \alpha=5\implies 
m\ge2 \sqrt{\dfrac{5}{3}},\, n = \pm \sqrt{m^2 - \dfrac{20}{3}}.\quad$
This means that, while $\,\alpha=5\,$ is congruent number, being an integer area of a right triangle, it is not the area of any Pythagorean triple which requires integers for all sides.

Therefore, Euclid's formula and the area-derived formula you supplied cannot be used to describe all congruent numbers.

Comment: here $\delta = 1$

Comment: and 1 is perfect square 1*1 = 1

Comment: @Life_is_pie The sides of the triangle are not integers for $\alpha=5$ so the formula cannot generate it using integers for $m,n$, Integers are required for divisibility.

Comment: where is flaw then because $f=bd$ is true.

Comment: so it is true for congruent numbers with corresponding triangle whose legs are not integers.

Comment: Choose $m=5$ and $n=4$ Then $a = (m-n)(m+n)=1\cdot 9=9$, $b = 2\cdot m\cdot n= 2\cdot 3\cdot 2 = 12$. Both $a$ and $b$ are not square free so we can break them up by factoring the largest non square free part of both $a$ and $b$ as $a=3\cdot 3=9$ and $b=2\cdot 20 $. Write $c^2 = (9)^2+(40)^2 = (3\cdot3)^2 +(2\cdot 20)^2$ then it follows that the integer $n = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{2})(\frac{20}{3}) =5$ is a congruent number generated by the triple $(\frac{3}{2},\frac{20}{3}, \frac{41}{6})$. This is precisely the triple that Fibonacci discovered in 1220 in response to his challenger. Here $f=bd$

Comment: 12 was suppose to be 20 and then $mn*(m-n)(m+n) = 9* 20$ which is divisible by 5 so we have $mn(m-n)(m+n)/ 36 = 5$ with $m=5$ and $n=4$